# How Angular "$watchs" arrays but wont watch properties?

Tags: angularjs, watch

I have two controllers communicating via a service (factory).

`OfficerCtrl` and `NotificationCtrl` they communicate via the `notification` service.

Here's the `NotificationCtrl` and the `notification` service.

```
angular.module('transimat.notification', [])
.controller('NotificationsCtrl', function($scope, notification) {
    $scope.msgs = notification.getMsgs();
    $scope.showNotification = false;
    $scope.$watchCollection('msgs', function() {

    //put break point here: It enters
        $scope.showNotification = $scope.msgs.length > 0;
    });
    $scope.close = function(index) {
        notification.close(index);
    };

    $scope.showModal = false;
    $scope.modalMsg = notification.getModalMsg();
    $scope.$watch('modalMsg', function() {

    //put break point here: Wont enter
        $scope.showModal = $scope.modalMsg !== null;
    },
    true);

})
.factory('notification', function($interval) {
    var severity = ['success','info','warning','danger','default'];

    var msgs = [];

    var modalMsg = null;

    var notification = {

        showSuccess: function(summary, detail, delay) {
            showMsg(severity[0], summary, detail, delay);
        },

        //...

        close: function(index) {
            msgs.splice(index,1);
            return msgs;
        },

        getMsgs: function() {
            return msgs;
        },

        // MODALS
        getModalMsg: function() {
            return modalMsg;
        },

        showModalMsg: function(summary, detail, uri) {
            modalMsg = {
                summary: summary,
                detail: detail,
                uri: uri
            };
        },

        closeModal: function() {
            modalMsg = null;
        }
    };

    var showMsg = function(severity, summary, detail, delay) {

        var msg = {
            severity: severity,
            summary: summary,
            detail: detail
        };
        msgs.push(msg);
        if (delay > 0) {
            $interval(function() {
                msgs.splice(msgs.length - 1, 1);
            }, delay, 1);
        }
    };

    return notification;
});
```

That's my notification ctrl/service.

Now in my `OfficerCtrl` I "push" notifications via the notification service.

```
angular.module('transimat.officers', [])
.controller('RegisterOfficerCtrl', function (
    $scope,
    notification) {
    // business logic
// this WONT work
    $scope.showModal = function(){
        notification.showModalMsg('NOW','BLAH','officer/1234');
    }
// this works
    $scope.showNotification = function() {
        notification.showSuccess('Success', 'Blah blah.', 5000);
    };

})
```

It will watch arrays but wont watch "normal" vars.
So I have to questions:

- The showNotification() works, but the showModal() wont work. It has to do with some pointer thing? The Arrays have a "strong" pointer and the normal vars have "weak" pointers and get ignored/lost by the $scope.$watch expression?
- How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first watch watches the array of messages `msgs` of your controller scope, which is the array returned by the service `getMsgs()` function. So, each time the content of this array changes, the callback function is called. When `showSuccess()` is called, a new message is pushed to the array, and the callback is thus called.

The second watch watches the field `modalMsg` of your controller. So, each time a new value is assigned to `$scope.modalMsg`, or each time it's not equal to its previous value, the callback function is called. But a new value is never assigned to this variable. It's only assigned once, before the watch is created. The `showModalMsg()` function of the service assigns a new value to its own, private, `modalMsg` variable, but doesn't assign any new value to the controller's `modalMsg` variable, which still references the old notification `modalMsg` object:

Before showModalMsg():

```
$scope.modalMsg -----------------> object
                                     ^
                                     |
notification modalMsg ---------------|
```

After showModalMsg():

```
$scope.modalMsg -----------------> object


notification modalMsg -----------> other object
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains the why. I tested putting the `modalMsg` in the notifications var, and it didn't worked. How can I make the change to the same object. Sorry, I'm not that proficient in JavaScript to understand at once what I have to do. How do I modify the object of the `notificationCtrl` via the `OfficerCtrl` to make it work?

Comment: I figured out. If you let me edit your answer for completeness.